# How to get rid of Google invasion?

Tags: google, performance

The performance of my phone became very poor. It's very slow. When I open the wifi, it freezes for a few minutes! I had to **reset factory default**.

After the resetting, the phone became super fast once again but I found some pre-installed apps that may make my phone slow again such as Facebook, Messenger, Whatsapp, ...etc. I deleted all of them but I can't get rid of Google products. I can only disable them. I don't know why Google imposes their products. I have the right to manage my internal memory the way I like!

Here is a list of the products that consume the internal memory as well as the performance:

- Chrome
- Google Play Store
- Google Drive
- Gmail
- Google App
- Google play music
- Google Play services
- Google Hangouts
- Google Maps
- Google Photos

Would you tell me how to get rid of them, please? I have Android Marshmallow 6.0

Comment: Generally here, going Google-free is the arena of moderator [Izzy](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/16575/izzy). See the user profile with expertise in the form of links to explore Google-free options including app substitution, eradication, and the like, and related info about that topic.

Comment: Indeed I run my devices "Google-free". Easiest way to achieve this is to install a custom ROM like LineageOS – as for license reasons, those come without the so-called "GApps". Once those "GApps" are installed, it's hard to get rid of them in any othe way.